# Flask-LDAP installation on windows box

Tags: python, ldap

I'm trying to set up single sign on using Python Flask on a windows box.

It looks like Flask-LDAP or Flask-Kerberos is what I should be using but I can't seem to install it using pip on a Windows box.

The installation fails with an error:

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory

Does anyone have any experience doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It's failing to install a prereq. I used Christoph Gohlke's python-ldap wheel to install [python-ldap](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap). Once python-ldap was installed, `pip install Flask-LDAP` ran successfully.

I don't use Flask-Kerberos, so I'm not sure which component fails to install there, but it likely has a similar resolution. Figure out which prereq is failing, find the unofficial Windows wheel for it, then try again with the prereq already installed.